# Can I detect if my PWA is launched as an app or visited as a website?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

If I have a PWA I might want to ask my user to add it to their launcher, but I don't want to ask this if it's actually launched from the launcher.

Is there any way to detect this from javascript?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For android, you should only prompt users to install after receiving a `beforeinstallprompt` event. This event will only be fired if the PWA has not already been installed.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen
  btnAdd.style.display = 'block';
});
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

For IOS, you can check `window.navigator.standalone`, which should be true if the app has already been installed.

```
// Detects if device is on iOS 
const isIos = () => {
  const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return /iphone|ipad|ipod/.test( userAgent );
}
// Detects if device is in standalone mode
const isInStandaloneMode = () => ('standalone' in window.navigator) && (window.navigator.standalone);

// Checks if should display install popup notification:
if (isIos() && !isInStandaloneMode()) {
  // offer app installation here
}
```

https://www.netguru.co/codestories/few-tips-that-will-make-your-pwa-on-ios-feel-like-native

Comment: What is "this" in this context?

Comment: @paul This is probably react code? (this.setState({ showInstallMessage: true });)
There is no setState on the window object. If this is react code, the answer should mention that. This makes it seem like there is an ios specific browser implementation of setState.

Comment: @JørgenAndersen yes, that was some redux code, have removed it from answer

Comment: on iOS, PWA works just with Safari, right?

Comment: @paul Do you have any idea how we can trigger install prompt from dart code. I have a flutter app where All UI part is in dart files. So I have a landing page where I want to detect if PWA is installed then show nothing. If native app is installed show open in app button. If nothing installed show Add to Home banner and install PWA. I already have manifest.json for PWA. It shows add to home in mobile chrome browsers but only once. I want to trigger it each time like other apps are doing for example reddit/myjio etc.

Answer (score 2):

To put it in another way, you dont have to do any code to achieve this. Browser triggeres Install to home screen banner/related events, only if its used in a browser and wont happen from launcher.

What you expect to do is the default behavior of how web install banners work.

Comment: But what if I don't want to ask right away, or want the "adding" to be an active action without finding the "Add to launcher" shortcut that they seem to be hiding deeper and deeper in settings?

Comment: You don’t have to ask right away. Listen for the event beforeinstallprompt which chrome will trigger when it thinks appropriate (not when it’s launched from launcher(which solves your original question) and when all PWA criteria are met. You can’t make the browser force trigger this event. All you can do is only catch it When it’s triggered and use it to show the Install prompt when you think it’s good time to show.

Comment: @Anand iOS Safari doesn't support `beforeinstallprompt` see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Comment: @snoob Dogg .. Not just the beforeinstallprompt. Whole install prompt use case is not applicable for iOS. Only way to add to home screen in iOS is via safari menu, which is also not available for iOS chrome. This thread is only for the use case where prompt does work.